# How to make an application run on as a cloud service

Tags: android, cloud

I had developed an android app.
Now I want to make the app run as a cloud service .
Is it possible to do that.
if possible please tell me a way to achieve it...

Comment: still that is not possible. you need to write cloud service separately using cloud technology apis.

Answer (score 0):

This is wildly dependent on what your android app does and your expectations of how it will continue to do that as a cloud service.

For example, if your application is a static page that displays information, and you want to be able to access that outside of android, you can run an android emulator on Linux and have that Linux VM running in the cloud. This is not really a cloud service, but might accomplish what you are trying to do.

If your app has business logic like taking some numbers and doing some calculations, you should really look at porting your android app to another language that can run specifically on a Windows or Linux VM. This involves learning a new language, researching APIs, and a basic understanding of the cloud provider you choose to use.

As a starting point, this example project is a very basic but modern template for Java cloud services. It uses a framework called Spring to help simplify some of the API understanding but would provide a somewhat easy transition from the Android world.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-simple

From there you need to research how to run the application on a Linux VM using tomcat.

http://tomcat.apache.org/

Finally, you will need to understand the cloud platform's VM provisioning as well as some basic networking concepts. Amazon's AWS is an easy to learn, developer friendly platform that has a ton of documentation and tutorials widely available.

Comment: Sure, no problem. If this was helpful feel free to accept this answer using the check mark.